# commander.js not parsing input

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I am using commander.js to make a server start script with a `-e` flag to set `NODE_ENV` however when i do `./bin/start -e development` it returns true instead of the input code below

```
var program = require('commander');
var sh = require('sh');

program
    .version('1.0.0')
    .option('-e, --enviroment', 'set NODE_ENV varible')
    .parse(process.argv);

console.log('running: NODE_ENV ' + program.enviroment + ' node index.js');
sh('NODE_ENV ' + program.enviroment + 'node index.js');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something in square brackets in there:

```
.option('-e, --enviroment [env]', 'set NODE_ENV varible')
```

They are used to determine an amount of arguments there.

Comment: Is the label `env` used for anything?